# Caught somewhere between argparse and import function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, include, argparse

Here is my problem:

I have a function, that gets for example some arguments:

```
import argparse

default_1 = 1
default_2 = [12, 34]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("I", type=int)
parser.add_argument("N")
parser.add_argument("P", nargs='?', default=default_2)
parser.add_argument("C", nargs='?', type=int, default=default_1)
args = parser.parse_args()

def testfunc(I, N, ARG1=default_1, ARG2=default_2):
    print(I, N, ARG1, ARG2)

testfunc(args.I, args.N, ARG1=args.C, ARG2=args.P)
```

When I call it from the shell with

```
>>> python3.2 test.py 2 foo
2 foo 1 [12,34]
```

which is what I expected. But if I add a `C 5` parameter:

```
>>> python3.2 test.py 2 foo C 5
3 foo 5 C
```

instead of

```
3 foo 5 [12, 34]
```

which is certainly because I f**ked something up with the argparse.

The next odd thing is, when I call this function (`python3.2 test2.py`) from my other file `test2.py` like this:

```
from test.py import testfunc
testfunc(2, 'bar')
```

returns me:

```
usage: test2.py [-h] I N [P] [C]
test2.py: error: too few arguments
```

Update #1:
When I remove `args = parser.parse_args()` (or comment it) in the `test.py` file, the `import testfunc` works. Why is that so?

Update #2:
I came closer to the core of the problem (that's what I want to think at least ...) - with (in the `test.py`):

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

I get `test2.py` as output, where I thought I would get `test.py` - so the argparser from the included function still thinks there are command line arguments being shovled it's way. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Why exactly "can't use the script itself with argparse anymore"? What's not working? Do you have an error message? The description of the problem is very vague.

Comment: The connection between your use of `argparse` and this `function` is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used

```
print(args)
```

instead of the `testfunc` the parsing might be clearer.  I expect it to show

```
Namespace(I=2, N='foo', P='C', C=5)
```

That is, it assigns `2, foo, C, 5` to `I, N, P, C` respectively.

You seem to be mixing the defaults as assigned by `argparse` with those used by `testfunc` keyword arguments.

---

I suspect you wanted `C 5` to be interpreted as 'assign 5 to argument labeled C'.  But that's not how positional arguments are treated.  If you had defined `-p` and `-c` argument, then you could have used:

```
2 foo -c 5
```

and gotten the desired behavior

Comment: yeah maybe I do that. I want to have the `testfunc` available as an imported function that I can use in other files. But I dont always have all the arguments it needs to be called. This is where my confusion comes from.

Comment: Better to say: I don't always want to give the function all arguments. Then it should take standard arguments, which is what I tried also to keep with arg.parse

Comment: How about using `-p` and `-c` arguments.  Make them optionals (with flags) rather than optional ('?') positionals.  `argparse` optionals correspond to functional keyword arguments,

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, `'C'` is not a flag marking the next value, is treated as a value itself.

Comment: You mean like `parser.add_argument("-P", default=default_2)` this? But I still get the `too few arguments` error on import :(

Comment: Removing the `nargs='?'` did a good job - still I can't figure where the `too few arguments` error is burried :(

Comment: Move the `args = parser.parse_args()`, or whole parser definition to a `if __name__...` block so it isn't run when you just import the module.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that is you provide more positional arguments than are defined that 'extra' positional arguments become the keyword arguments in order.

```
def function(arg1, arg2=None):
    if arg2:
        return arg1 + arg2
    else:
        return arg1


assert function(1, 2) == function(1, arg2=2)
assert function(1) == function(1, 0) == function(1, arg2=0)
assert not ''  #  Empty string is falsy
```